# Gmail API, only snippets from Twitter emails contain bunch of \u200c characters instead of the real snippets

Tags: python, email, oauth-2.0, gmail-api

This is how I am getting list of threads:

```
page = resource.users().threads().list(
                userId='me', q='category: social',
                maxResults=50).execute()
threads_list = page.get('threads', [])
```

And when I print **threads_list**, I get something like this:

```
[{'id': '16643b797b5cf72d', 'snippet': 'Some normal thread snippet.', 'historyId': '461733'}, {'id': '16642fea8db13893', 'snippet': '\u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c \u200c', 'historyId': '461679'}]
```

In gmail snippet of one email from twitter is: "Windows 10 will eventually let you mirror your Android phone's apps", but instead of that I get bunch of **zero width non-joiner characters**...

And just snippets from twitter are like this, every other snippet is normal.
I am using now deprecated **oauth2client** to run the flow, maybe this is the problem but I am not sure.